# filter Records using Dropdownlist in a Datalist and Datatable

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, datalist

Here I need to filter Data using `Dropdownlist` in `Datalist`

i Have more than 1000 Records everything its stored with their Category Name....

its in String(A,B,C,D......to Z) and

i have some values in dropdownlist(1.2,3,5,10,all) here how i need filter the data in datalist means by dropdownindex changed to 1 in that case it show only the record which available in alphabet A,

if index changed 2 it Should show the records od A & B ......As so on...by indexing to all it should show all the Record in the database....

Comment: probably easier for us if you add some code and example data.

Answer (score 0):

Set the AutoPostBack property of DropDownlist to true and use the SelectedIndexChanged event..

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DDwn1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDwn1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Sort ascending" Value="ASC"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Sort descending" Value="DESC"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>


 private void showData(string sortDirection)
    {
        //bind to data list
    }

    protected void DDwn1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        showData(DDwn1.SelectedValue);
    }
```